# what's the main advantage of 3d rendering for architecture?

Tags: design-principles

3d rendering service is popular in architecture company, what's the main advantage of it? The effect of this rendering can fully present the design concept? How can we adjust the model?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about graphic design. Sorry about that.  Ask an architect instead.

Comment: Visualisations are very useful in communicating the subject. Not only to laypeople, but to designers themselves too (this is one of the reason people also do virtual reality stuff as you get a instant realisation of scale, like no other computer peripheral does. You can hardly 3D print mockups of buildings).

Comment: This is what I've spent a lot of time doing the last decade - architectural illustrations and renderings, both more traditional and 3D CGI. Basic premise is that most decisionmakers in AEC aren't designers, architects or contractors, so though they may have a rudimentary ability to "read" drawings, they cannot themselves visualise the built condition, or materiality, from those 2D drawings, no matter how well done. So, traditionally, we presented hand-illustrated, hand-coloured perspective vignettes to illustrate final lived experience, with entourage, shadows, and scale figures.

Comment: This became, over time, a focal point for those decision makers - the imaginative how-it-might look which conveys character - it's like a more-detailed study model being shown to the client - doesn't pin everything down too hard, but conveys massing and materiality and rhythms...

Comment: And once 3D CGI became in-reach for some higher tech shops, it rapidly became a desired style or approach. One can start with a BIM model (Revit, ArchiCAD, et al) and export that model, or one can start from 2D CAD drawings and 3D model manually... and then either render out stills, plan, animate and render out a movie, or these days, export the model to a game engine and have a real-time rendered output. The idea however, is still the same as the hand-drawn perspective vignettes - to show character, lighting, materiality and some sense of use-case.

Comment: The biggest counter-argument against 3D CGI is that in the looser hand drawings, there was little discrete detail, and the viewer could thus read into the drawing what they wished - and so didn't get hung up on irrelevant materiality details early in the design process - with CGI, even the early concept renders can look super-finished, which can lead to distraction discussions where you want to address rough massing / envelope alignment, site planning etc. and the client is stuck on telling you why they hate the brick pattern on that one wall; thus sometimes loose sketchy hand-done is best.

Comment: @BillyKerr - I'm not sure I agree - this is specifically about the design and communications rationale for using renders in graphical communication of design intent with a design client - using graphic design tools and concepts, presentation concepts, and illustration skill all in a graphically-designed client-facing presentation - I think it obtains, and occupies the intersection space between sheer graphic design and architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the question is. Architecture is a highly technical subject, so real estate investors usually pay for 3D models / renderings / videos of their property before the property is actually built, so the customers can see what they're paying for (for example in an apartment building), or retail managers can see what a space looks like before signing a lease deal (for example in a shopping mall). This way investors can start selling units and rent space before or while the actual building is being developed.